# Polymer - reload core-list data

Tags: polymer

I wanted reload a core-list element to show new data, but it´s not refreshing.
I re-call the JS function thats generate the data but doesn t work... and reload like a 'normal' div doesn t work either! The list only shows the new data if i reload the entire page...

```
function values(sender, textomsg, datacriacao, senderfoto){
   var sender2 = sender.split(",");
   var textomsg2 = textomsg.split(",");
   var datacriacao2 = datacriacao.split(",");
   var senderfoto2 = senderfoto.split(",");

   var namegen = {
       generateString: function (inLength) {
           var s = '';
           for (var i = 0; i < inLength; i++) {
               s += String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 97);
           }
           return s;
       },
       generateName: function (inMin, inMax) {
           return this.generateString(Math.floor(Math.random() * (inMax - inMin + 1) + inMin));
       }
};

Polymer('list-test', {

    count: sender.length,
    ready: function () {
        this.data = this.generateData();

    },
    generateData: function () {
        var names = [], data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            names.push(namegen.generateName(4, 8));
        }
        names.sort();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            data.push({
                index: i,
                sender: sender2[i],
                textomsg: textomsg2[i],
                datacriacao: datacriacao2[i],
                senderfoto: senderfoto2[i]
            });
        }

        return data;

    },
    tapAction: function (e) {
        console.log('tap', e);
    }
});

}
```

<%----%>

```
<template id="templateConversas" runat="server">

  <div id="item" class="item {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}"  ><%--onClick="conversa('{{name}}');"--%>
    <div class="message" style="background-image: url({{senderfoto}});">
      <span class="from"><br/>{{sender}}</span>
      <span class="timestamp">{{datacriacao}}</span>
      <div class="subject"><br/>{{textomsg}} </div><%--------Infinite List. {{index}}--%>
      <%--<div class="body"><br/>Mensagem de teste...........</div>--%>
    </div>
  </div>

     </template>
```

The problem is also reload the 'list-test'. if i call the js function after the list is loaded it doesn't apply the new data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't complete so it is hard to understand but I think that the problem is that you don't assign the result of the `generateData()` function to the template's model. Try following script for your component

```
Polymer('list-test', {
  created: function () {
     this.data = [];
  },
  refresh: function () {
     this.data = this.generateData();
  },
  generateData: function () {
    // your original code here
  }
});
```

Now the list content should be updated with newly generated data when you call `refresh()` of the `list-test` element. To fill the list when element is created add

```
ready: function () {
   this.refresh();
},
```

Comment: how do i call the funtion (refresh) from another js ? i pass the values to the JS function (values) from code behind... thats why the code isn't complete... sorry :)

Comment: The same you would call any "standard" element's method, ie setAttribute() - you need to get reference to the node/element you want to work with and then you can access it's properties and call it's methods.

Comment: The problem is also reload the 'list-test'. if i call the js function after the list is loaded it doesn't apply the new data...how can i reload the element??? thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: The refresh method of your `list-test` element should change the content of the list - as far as I understand the generateData() generates bunch of random data... the problem might be that the element's `count` property isnt properly initialized... set it to `count: 10` and see do you have 10 new strings now each time you call refresh.

Comment: ok...i set it to ten and its the same but only with 10 rows...when i call refresh is generating the data, but i guess it doesn't show it because the data it's not being bounded to the 'list-test'... its shows the same content. if i call this document.getElementById('list-test').count = 2; the list will pass to the 10 to 2 rows... but if i call document.getElementById('list-test').refresh(); doesn.t show the new data...it stays the same...

Comment: for some reason i'm not passing the new data values to the generatedata...thats why it is not showing... all you say works perfectly thank you so much :)